# Nombre de una Variable de Clase a partir de una string

Tags: python, clase, instancias

Amigos ojala me puedan ayudar, no se si lo que quiero haces es posible.

En una clase en python, quiero a partir de una variable string crear  el nombre de una variable de instancia, nombrar variables
de la clase, ejemplo:

```py
class Personas:

    def __init__(self):
        nombre_de_la_variable='Persona1'

        self.[nombre] = 'Pedro' # Aqui se produce un error 

        #quiero poder hacer este llamado

        print(self.Persona1)

        # el resultado del print deberia ser Pedro.
```

Comment: Puedes usar [setattr](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functions.html#setattr)

Answer (score 0):

No tiene ningún sentido crear valores fijos dentro de una función o una clase (`self._algo = 'Pedro'`), ya que todas las instancias "heredarán" esos valores constantes. A menos que quieras hacer un [método o propiedad estática](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+static+method), pero ya eso es otro asunto.

Para que un objeto devuelva *"un resultado"* al ser llamado directamente, se puede definir en su clase el método especial `__str__` o `__repr__` [Ver documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__):

```py
class Personas:
    def __init__(self, nombre):
        self.nombre = nombre
        
    def __str__(self): # Esto se ejecuta al ser llamada la instancia
        return self.nombre
```

Entonces creando algunas instancias:

```py
persona1 = Personas('Pedro')
persona2 = Personas('Juan')
#
# Imprimiendo los objetos:
print(persona1) # Imprime: 'Pedro'
print(persona2) # Imprime: 'Juan'
```